# Updating Umbraco client files

Tags: umbraco, umbraco4

I just applied the fix from https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/24203-Anchor-changes-into-img-tag#comment-152217 into my /umbraco_client/tinymce3/themes/umbraco/js/anchor.js code, and restarted the website on my IIS, but that doesn't seem to apply the change in the umbraco client...

Is there any other action that is required to "update" the umbraco client so that I will see this change in my browser?

I am using Umbraco v 4.5.2 (Assembly version: 1.0.5253.25849)

Kind Regards,
Jonathan

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your browser cache (Ctrl + F5)?

Comment: Open up the dev tool in chrome and check the option `disable chache` on tab network.

Comment: @JannikAnker I have tried both of these solutions but neither of them worked, I tried recycling the folder & the application pool as well but that didn't work either...

Comment: @ninjaonsafari I have tried both of these solutions but neither of them worked, I tried recycling the folder & the application pool as well but that didn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the ClientDependency.config in /config. Within here, increment the version on the client dependency node.

i.e. 
clientDependency version=**"1"** fileDependencyExtensions=".js,.css"

Also remove the cache, TEMP, and Umbraco.config from App_Data, these will regenerate when you run the project.